# Javascript - Trying to contain objects inside dynamic properties

Tags: javascript, loops, object, properties

I have a function that creates an object and saves it as an ID in another object:

```
var enemyList = {}; //global var

Enemy = function () {
  var id = Math.random(); //random id
  var enemy = {
    some properties
  };
  enemyList.id = enemy;
}
```

Now, I found 'for loop' while searching online and I edited in order to update every id which contain an enemy object ref:

```
setInterval(update, 40); //execute update all the time
var frameCount = 0; //global var

function update {
  if (frameCount % 100 === 0) //  spawns new enemy every 4 seconds
    Enemy();

  for (var key in enemyList) {
    enemyList.key.update(); //move them around...     
  }
}
```

Every 4 seconds a new enemy is created, then that loop is supposed to move each enemy according to some logic... the thing is, once a new enemy is created, it replaces the old enemy, moves around and then is replaced by the next spawned enemy even though it shouldn't since they have unique ids. Why does it happen?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Could you include the implementation of the enemyList var? Please fix your indentation as well.

Answer (score 2):

When you say

```
enemyList.id = enemy;
```

you are actually setting the `enemy` object to the `id` property of `enemyList` object, you are not creating a new property with the value of `id`. It should have been

```
enemyList[id] = enemy;
```

The same is applicable for the `for` loop as well.

```
enemyList[key].update();
```

---

**Additional suggestions:**

1. The `for..in` will get all the enumerable, inherited properties of the `enemyList` object, not just the properties on it. So, it is not quite normal to have an `if` condition around in it, like this

   ```
   for (var key in enemyList) {
     if (enemyList.hasOwnProperty(key)) // make sure it is the own property
       enemyList.key.update();          // move them around...
   }
   ```
2. `setInterval(update, 40);` means that the `update` will be executed every 40 milliseconds, not `4` seconds. So, it should have been `setInterval(update, 4000);`

Comment: Can you explain more about using enemyList[id] = enemy; instead of enemyList.id = enemy; ? what is the difference? they are both converted to a random number eventually, are they not?

Comment: Let us say, `id` is 0.5. Now, `enemyList.id` means a property `id` in `enemyList`, not `enemyList[0.5]`

Comment: Alright first of all thank you, your code works, that [] did fix the problem. so, you are saying that the id in enemyList.id is not replaceable by prior vars(like var id = random), so why is it replaceable while using enemyList[id] ? The way I maybe understand it now, is that while using [id]  javascript actually expects a var.

Comment: Okay, lets approach this problem in a different way. How would you create a property called `name` on `enemyList`?

Comment: enemyList.name I suppose.

Comment: Now, what if I already had something like `var name = 'thefourtheye'` before that? Will it make any difference?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92280/discussion-between-user2081462-and-thefourtheye).